# Ошибка Oracle: "ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error"

Tags: oracle, установка

Здравствуйте! Установил на домашний компьютер Оракл 11g. Запускаю приложение SQL Plus и ввожу данные пользователя по умолчанию. Логин: su, пароль пустой. Вместе входа вываливает ошибку: "ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error".  Помогите найти, где настраиваются пароли и логины пользователей оракла.

Comment: Ответить нет желающих?

Comment: Советую найти пошаговую инструкцию по становке Oracle DB. И будет даже лучше, если она окажется с картинками.

Answer (score 4):

1. Вы ничего не написали о том, создали instance БД или нет.
2. Проверьте, запущен ли TNS listener: tnsping `%ORACLE_SID%`.
3. Самый простой способ проверить, поднята БД правильно или нет `telnet localhost 1521`.
4. Запустить service.msc и визуально проверить состояние сервисов с названием Oracle*  сервиса, в особености `OracleService%ORACLE_SID%`.

`ORACLE_SID` - это имя инстанса вашей БД. Обычно оракл создает эту переменную автоматически. Проверить можно так: echo `%ORACLE_SID%` (в принципе вы должны ее знать - раз ставили БД сами).

Гуглить : `ask tom ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS: protocol adapter error`.

Answer (score 2):

Я устанавливал дома Оракл 11g Express Edition. При установке Setup спросил имя-пароль, где-то запомнил и все работает.

При попытке зайти с неверным паролем у меня **ошибка ORA-01017**. IMHO у Вас проблема с сетевыми настройками (например с Firewall). Опишите подробнее ОС, версия, что включено и т.п.

Comment: Операционная система xp, что потавлена на виртуальной машине. Там же стоит оракл. Никаких файрволов и его подобных программ туда не ставил. Машина локальная, т.е. сеть не настроеена на интеграцию с другими компьютерами. Где можно посмотреть по коду ошибки и узнать признак-причину ошибки.

Comment: Google: **ORA-12560** выдает примерно 642 000 разных ответов.

IMHO попробуйте настроить виртуалку и XP так, чтобы интернет (oracle.com) был виден.

Comment: насколько я помню при установке XE просит указать только пароль. Стандартные логины: SYS или SYSTEM.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте решение с отключением `UAC` в `Windows`:

[Как победить ошибку ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error в Windows](http://konurbaev-e.blogspot.ru/2013/03/ora-12560-tnsprotocol-adapter-error.html).